# pg_column_size reports different vastly sizes for table.* than specific columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple example where pg_column_size is reporting vastly different values. I think it has to do with whether or not it's considering TOASTed values, but I'm not sure. Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (repeat('foo', 100000));
SELECT pg_column_size(bar) as col, pg_column_size(foo.*) as table FROM foo;
```

What I'm seeing in Postgres 9.6 is,

```
col     table
3442    300028
```

There's an order of magnitude difference here. Thoughts? What's the right way for me to calculate the size of the row? One idea I have is,

```
SELECT pg_column_size(bar), pg_column_size(foo.*) - octet_length(bar) + pg_column_size(bar) FROM foo;
```

Which should subtract out the post-TOAST size and add in the TOAST size.

**Edit:** My proposed work around only works on character columns, e.g. won't work on JSONB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first value is the compressed size of the TOASTed value, while the second value is the uncompressed size of the whole row.

```
SELECT 'foo'::regclass::oid;
┌───────┐
│  oid  │
├───────┤
│ 36344 │
└───────┘
(1 row)

SELECT sum(length(chunk_data)) FROM pg_toast.pg_toast_36344;
┌──────┐
│ sum  │
├──────┤
│ 3442 │
└──────┘
(1 row)
```

`foo.*` (or `foo` for that matter) is a “wholerow reference” in PostgreSQL, its data type is `foo` (which is created when the table is created).

PostgreSQL knows that `foo.bar` is stored externally,  so it returns its size as it is in the TOAST table, but `foo` (a composite type) isn't, so you get the total size.

See the relevant piece of code from `src/backend/access/heap/tuptoaster.c`:

```c
Size
toast_datum_size(Datum value)
{
    struct varlena *attr = (struct varlena *) DatumGetPointer(value);
    Size        result;

    if (VARATT_IS_EXTERNAL_ONDISK(attr))
    {
        /*
         * Attribute is stored externally - return the extsize whether
         * compressed or not.  We do not count the size of the toast pointer
         * ... should we?
         */
        struct varatt_external toast_pointer;

        VARATT_EXTERNAL_GET_POINTER(toast_pointer, attr);
        result = toast_pointer.va_extsize;
    }
    [...]
    else
    {
        /*
         * Attribute is stored inline either compressed or not, just calculate
         * the size of the datum in either case.
         */
        result = VARSIZE(attr);
    }
    return result;
}
```